# Set Paragraph in existing PDF file with Link to another page

Tags: c#, itext7

I need to add an Index to a PDF file with a link to its corresponding page.
I have the arrays of type Paragraphs to insert in each page of the pdf corresponding to the index.
I have created a simplification of the project so that we can do a simple test that solves the same problem: Create a clickable index. Now, it adds the texts, but they do not have any link to the pages I want them to jump to.

The main code is:

```
public string CreateIndex(string source, string destination)
{
    // Title to write in Index's Page 1
    Link[] chapters = new Link[4] { new Link(6, "Notes" ), new Link(7, "Presentation"), new Link(8, "Summary"), new Link(9, "Families") };
    // List of itext.Layout.Element.Paragraph
    List<Paragraph> lchapters = new List<Paragraph>();
    // Paragraph's Y Position
    int bottom = Constants.initialBottom;

    // For each Line to write in Index
    foreach (Link l in chapters)
    {
        // Create a Paragraph element
        Paragraph p = PDF.CreateText(l.Text, Constants.fontSize, Constants.backColor, Constants.fontColor, Constants.initialLeft, bottom, Constants.width);
        // Make Paragraph Linkable
        PDF.CreateClicableParagraph(ref p, l.Page);
        // Add to List of Paragraphs
        lchapters.Add(p);
        // New Y Position
        bottom -= Constants.jumpDown;
    }

    // Create a temporaly PDf with Index's Page 1 writed with linked Paragrapfs
    string temp_dest = destination.Replace(".pdf", "temp.pdf");
    PDF.ModifyPageDocument(source, temp_dest, lchapters.ToArray(), 3);

    // The same process to write a second Index Page
    chapters = new Link[2] { new Link(19, "Annex"), new Link(20, "Backcover") };
    lchapters = new List<Paragraph>();
    bottom = Constants.abajoInicial;

    foreach (Link l in chapters)
    {
        Paragraph p = PDF.CreateText(l.Text, Constants.fontSize, Constants.backColor, Constants.fontColor, Constants.initialLeft, bottom, Constants.width);
        PDF.CreateClicableParagraph(ref p, l.Page);
        lchapters.Add(p);
        bottom -= Constants.jumpDown;
    }

    PDF.ModifyPageDocument(temp_dest, destination, lchapters.ToArray(), 4);

     return destination;
}
```

The auxiliar clases I use are:

To manipulate de PDF objects (with iText). A class named PDF.

```
using iText.IO.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;

public static class PDF
{        
    public static void ModifyPageDocument(string src, string dest, Paragraph[] listText, int page)
    {            
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(page);
        PdfCanvas template = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(template, pdfPage.GetPageSize());

        foreach (Paragraph p in listText) canvas.Add(p);            

        pdfDoc.Close();
    }

    public static Paragraph CreateText(string text, float fontSize, string backColor, string fontColor, float left, float bottom, float width, bool bold = false, bool italic = false, bool underline = false, TextAlignment textAlign = TextAlignment.LEFT)
    {
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN), PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);
        p.SetFontSize(fontSize);

        if (bold) p.SetFont(font).SetBold();
        else p.SetFont(font);

        if (italic) p.SetItalic();

        if (underline) p.SetUnderline();

        if (backColor != null) p.SetBackgroundColor(GetColor(backColor));

        p.SetFixedPosition(left, bottom, width);
        p.SetTextAlignment(textAlign);
        p.SetFontColor(GetColor(fontColor));

        return p;
    }

    public static void CreateClicableParagraph(ref Paragraph p, int page)
    {
        p.SetAction(iText.Kernel.Pdf.Action.PdfAction.CreateGoTo(iText.Kernel.Pdf.Navigation.PdfExplicitRemoteGoToDestination.CreateFitB(page)));
    }

    public static DeviceRgb GetColor(string color)
    {
        switch (color)
        {
            case "WHITE":
                return (DeviceRgb)DeviceRgb.WHITE;

            case "BLACK":
                return (DeviceRgb)DeviceRgb.BLACK;

            default:
                return (DeviceRgb)DeviceRgb.WHITE;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, a Constants class and a class to construct the index elements:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static int initialBottom = 700;
    public static int initialLeft = 100;
    public static int width = 100;
    public static int jumpDown = 200;
    public static int fontSize = 12;
    public static string backColor = Color.White.Value;
    public static string fontColor = Color.Black.Value;
}    



public class Link
{
    public int Page;
    public string Text;

    public Link(int p, string t)
    {
        this.Page = p;
        this.Text = t;
    }
}
```

I think I am not forgetting anything. Hopefully you can help me. Thank you!!

Comment: Please add the source PDF you are trying to insert content into, and a sample of values to pass to the methods you attached.

Comment: It’s a dll and from database querys (from input variables) gets the info to create some pages and merge with existing PDF files. I can attach something similar but not the original information because I haven’t. PRE.pdf is the original file and POST.pdf is the file with the index I want create.

Comment: [PRE.pdf](https://clientes.tradelab.es/descarga.aspx?key=12575caa96c640d498037251ddcbd40d)  [POST.pdf](https://clientes.tradelab.es/descarga.aspx?key=79048368b6d54c3b9fc633d060f95727)

Comment: Yes, please attach all the necessary information in a minimal form to reproduce. I don't think anyone will guess which data to insert to reproduce :)

Comment: Sorry Alexey but I don't understand what are you requesting me. The pre.pdf file is the source file and the post.pdf file is the result what I want to get. The difference betwen both are the linked index that is what I need to resolve. Every line in the Index (pages 3-4) are a link to it's corresponding chapter. Do you need more code? Please sorry to don't undertand you.

Comment: Yep, no worries. So you attached some code into your question. How do I run it? Do I call `CreateClicableParagraph` before  `ModifyPageDocument`? What do I pass as `listText`? Please share the minimal code that is actually runnable

Comment: I have edited the original answer with the runnable code